# How do I make an applescript that presses the delete key using command down

Tags: applescript

I have this script that I have been working on to clear out my Caches and application support files I will skip to the part that I need help with;

---

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "o" using {command down}
        delay 0.5
    keystroke delete using {command down}
end tell
```

---

When the script gets to the keystroke delete using {command down} I get the error message;

> error "System Events got an error: Can’t continue using." number -1708

How can I improve?

Comment: You are mixing up AppleScript terminology with key codes. The AS `delete` command does not respond to key modifiers. Why do you use (a sort of) GUI scripting rather than deleting the files directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use not `keystroke`, but the related `key code` to access special keys.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 51 using {command down}
end tell
```

See [full reference of key codes here](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html).